# ngResource: accessing nested data in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I have created voting function in controller and after i switched to retrtiving my data via $resource clicking on upvote throws

> "$scope.question.activities[index] is undefined"

in the console.

How can i access deeply nested data from $resource in controller?

code:
 controller

```
 $scope.questions = QuestionService.query(function (result) {
    $scope.question = result[$routeParams.id - 1];
});
 $scope.plusOneA = function (index) {
    $scope.question.activities[index].voteCount += 1;
};
$scope.minusOneA = function (index) {
    $scope.question.activities[index].voteCount -= 1;
};
```

service

```
.factory('QuestionService', ['$resource', function($resource){
return $resource('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1uuml:id', {id: '@id'})
}])
```

data

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "voteCount": 0,
    "activities": [
        {
            "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "voteCount": -3 
        },
        {
            "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "voteCount": -3 
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: update the post with your controller code and the relevant functions

Comment: @Aravind it updated now

Comment: add your sample json data that your api returns

Comment: @Aravind it is done

Comment: @Aravind i've replaced [index] with [0]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130252/discussion-between-edgecrusher-and-aravind).

Comment: $scope.questions or $scope.question check spelling

Comment: @CognitiveDesire its not that. $resource wokrs  asynchronously so basicaly its not loaded to controller

Comment: please create a fiddle